# Heroku Review Apps - separated backend and frontend

Tags: heroku, staging

I started using Review Apps which works good. However I use separated backend and frontend (rails and ember) and I would like to set connection between new PR on backend and frontend. I think the easiest way is to create new env 'integration' in ember and set api host per each PR. It is possible to define environment of built ember app on new dynamic staging?

Answer (score 1):

If your Review App needs a dynamic API host, you could set it get the host from [Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). I would imagine it would be something like `ENV['API_URL']`. This approach is more in line with Heroku's stated best-practices as embodied in http://12factor.net/.

Also, if you want to have a default for new review apps, so you don't have to set this var for each new one, you should look at using an [app.json](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema) schema.